# Should I use AsyncTask or IntentService to download very small files from S3?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, android-asynctask

I am very new to multi threading and I think asyncTasks or IntentService may help me solve my problem.

What i want to do is that whenever the application is started it should download a file from S3 and set the data in persistent storage and also i need to inform the main thread when the download is complete and data in persistent storage is set.

So, what should i use? Or is there a third way which i may not have come across yet?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use WorkerManager or DownloadManager it will be more efficient.

Comment: what is S3 here ?

Comment: @AADProgramming sorry for missing it. I am referring to Amazon S3 storage service.

Comment: @YaroslavOvdiienko That download is merely a set of configurations (around a KB) that my app requires does the user need to know when it is being downloaded. Because as far as i know these are foreground tasks and the user will be notified in notifications.

Comment: @HardikBansal as I know WorkManager(JobScheduler deprecated) does not show any notification.